# Implement button_to in ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to have a button in my view, on click it should delete items from my DB table and refresh the view with updated DB contents. Below is the code in my index.html.erb file

```
   <div id="table-record">
<div class="table-order-detail" id="position1">
<div class="table-inner-border">
<% if @orders%>
<div class="bottom-border1"><%= "Table"+@orders.first.tableno %>
</div>
<div class="bottom-border1">
<div class="item-name">Item</div> <div class="qty">Qty</div>
</div>
<% @orders.each do |order| %>
<% if (order.itmstatus == "displayed") %>
<div class="item-name"><%= order.itemname %></div>
<div class="qty"><%= order.quantity %></div>
<% else %>
<div class="new-item-name"><%= order.itemname %></div>
<div class="qty"><%= order.quantity %></div>

<% end %>
<% end %>
<% end %>
<% button_to "Done", {:action => "doneorder", :id => @orders.first.tableno, :controller => "kitchens"}, :method => :delete %> 
</div></div>
```

@orders.first.tableno is the key based on which I need to delete rows from my DB table(not sure if I need to pass this in id field, but I found this syntax in one of the related posts)

Below is the code in my controller (kitchens). The controller had initially only index method defined. Now I have added another method doneorder which I need to call on my button click.

```
def doneorder

        List.where(:tableno => params[:id])).delete_all
        redirect_to :action => :index

  end
```

In above method I need to delete rows corresponding to id passed from button click and then redirect to index action. Index action will fetch updated rows from lists table and display updated contents.

I am totally beginner in rails and I have tried numerous  things from related posts including link_to but nothing seems to be working. With above code in place I get below error

```
No route matches {:action=>"doneoreder", :id=>"01", :controller=>"kitchens"}
```

In  my routes file I have given

```
resources :kitchens do
  put :done_order, on: :member
end
```

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: `<button type="submit" id="1">` please remove this html code no more required

Comment: Thanks. Tried as suggested. There is no error now but its not performing anything. Clicking on button is not doing anything. It remains on same page. I checked rails server and no activity is reflected.

Comment: Please see my post.....did you remove html tag? before button_to I mean `<button type="submit" id="1"> </button>`

Comment: and it should be `doneorder` not `done_order` in `routes` and in `view`

Comment: yes. I corrected doneorder and removed the html tag. On removing html tag the button is not visible at all. So I just kept <button> & </button>. I tried again with removing tags but then there is no button on screen.

Comment: please see my post below i only use `<%= button_to %>` no html tag  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18524998/implement-button-to-in-ror/18525225#18525225

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in routes

```
   resources :kitchens do 
    delete :doneorder 
  end
```

in view

`<%= button_to "Done", { :controller => "kitchens", :action => "doneorder", :id => @orders.first.tableno}, :method => :delete %>`

`<button type="submit" id="1">` please remove this html code no more required

Comment: I did exactly same as you have suggested but button is not visible now. Edited post and put the full code of index.html.erb file.

Comment: `<% button_to "Done", {:action => "doneorder", :id => @orders.first.tableno, :controller => "kitchens"}, :method => :delete %> ` where is equal to it should be `<%=` not `<%` in front of button_to look my post carefully

Comment: can you please copy and paste to replace your button to

Comment: Sincere Apologies for missing this. Its there now. I belive its working now, anyhow I am still checking it. Thanks again for everything.

Answer (score 0):

your route has `done_order` but your action is `doneorder`

so either change your route or the action name.

edit: you also don't need to enclose the button_to in a button tag.

you also need to add `:method => :put` in your button_to call. i hope you did not follow the route change in rajarshi's answer. if you did, change it back to `put` instead of `delete`

Comment: Thanks for pointing this. Corrected now. I made some additional changes as suggested by Rajasrshi. There is no error now but still its not working.

Comment: Thanks. On removing button tag the button isn't visible at all. I have updated my post and placed the more code from index.html.erb file.

Comment: your update is showing `<% button_to` it should be `<%= button_to` that's why the button is not showing.